# can you POST using fields that are not in a form

Tags: jquery, post

Is it possible to replace the hard-coded data "ss and bb with the values from "username" and "password" even though they are not contained within a form?  This is using POST.

Code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Hello World</title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#msgid").html("This is Hello World by JQuery");

 $("#clear").click(function(){
   $("#msgid").empty();
 });

 $("#submit").click(function(){

   $.post("/login", {username:"ss",password:"bb"}, function(data) {
     alert("post finished");
   });

 });


});

</script>

This is Hello World HTML

<div id="msgid">
</div>

<div id="content">
  <input type="text" id="username"></input>
  <input type="password" id="password"></input>


  <br><input type="button" value="clear" id="clear"></input>
  <br><input type="button" value="submit post" id="submit"></input>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** to get the value of your input:

```
{username:$('#username').val(),password:$('#password').val()}
```